# Error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_AppNavigator2.default.router') for React Navigation / Redux Implementation for React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to build a StackNavigator into my redux store using react-navigation, and I keep getting the error
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cgZU.png) (and mentioned above in the title).

Below is my code for my react-native project using redux.  The error is popping up on my reducer where I call `AppNavigator.router`.

## src/AppNavigator.js

```
import { StackNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Welcome from './screens/Welcome';
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard';
import Login from './screens/Login';

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Welcome: {
      screen: Welcome,
      navigationOptions: ({
        header: 'null',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontSize: 30,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
        },
      }),
    },
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard,
      navigationOptions: ({
        title: 'Dashboard',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontSize: 30,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
        },
        headerLeft: null,
      }),
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: ({
        title: 'Login or Register',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontSize: 30,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
        },
        headerLeft: null,
      }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
  },
);
```

## src/AppWithInternalState.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';

const AppWithInternalState = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
  <AppNavigator navigation={
    addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch,
      state: nav,
    })
  }/>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithInternalState);
```

## /src/reducers/navReducer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from '../AppNavigator';

const router = AppNavigator.router;
const mainNavAction = router.getActionforPathandParams('Welcome');
const initialNavState = router.getStateForAction(mainNavAction);

export default navReducer = (state = initialNavState, action) => (
  router.getStateForAction(action, state)
);
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import AppNavigator from '../AppNavigator';` -> AppNavigator is undefined because you dont have a default export.

In `AppNavigator.js` use `export default AppNavigator = StackNavigator` (notice the **default** instead of **const**).

Alternativ: `import { AppNavigator } from '../AppNavigator';` in `navReducer.js`